# JPG EXIF - Where from property

Tags: jpeg, exif

I made an image with my Samsung s7Edge. I emailed it to my gmail account. Then I downloaded the image on my Mac.

I checked the properties, and there was this property named Where from:
That had a around 2kb of data starting with my gmail account information.

Now, what is going on in here? Why and where is that written to the image file?

That had to be written during file download by a browser, but could be done by OS as well.

Would appreciate more information about this.

Comment: Attach your S7, download the image and compare the information. Depending on how you did it, compare downloading the image using google web application and a local e-mail client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Where from" is a metadata/attribute created by Mac. Gmail does not add information to it's attachments.

The same exact issue was discussed here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110239/where-is-the-where-from-meta-data-stored-when-downloaded-via-chrome